# Connection Refused even after adding a new Firewall rule

Tags: c, unix, firewall

I am trying to connect to my local UNIX server i made from another remote device. the Server is up and listening to the port i specified. i also added a new firewall rule to open that port but still my client cannot connect. it shows ERROR CONNECTION REFUSED

here is my server code

```
int main() {
  int fd, i,svclient,rval,msg;
  int clients[10], num_clients;
  fd_set read_set,write_set;
  char buf[100];

  struct sockaddr_in addr;

  if ( (fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("socket error");
    exit(-1);
  }


  bzero((char *) &addr, sizeof(addr));
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  addr.sin_port = htons(4001);

  //strncpy(addr.sun_path, socket_path, sizeof(addr.sun_path)-1);
  //strcpy(addr.sun_path, NAME);

  if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1) {
    perror("bind error");
    exit(-1);
  }
  printf("Bind complet...\n");

  if (listen(fd, 20) == -1) {
    perror("listen error");
    exit(-1);
  }

  num_clients = 0;
  int size = sizeof(fd);

   while (1) {

    int clientfd;
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    int addrlen=sizeof(client_addr);
    FD_ZERO(&read_set);
    FD_SET(fd, &read_set);

    for (i = 0; i < num_clients; i++) { //at first this part will not excute
      FD_SET(clients[i], &read_set);
    }

    select(fd + num_clients + 1, &read_set, NULL, NULL, NULL);


    if (FD_ISSET(fd, &read_set)) {
      if ( (clients[num_clients++] = accept(fd,(struct sockaddr*)&client_addr,&addrlen)) == -1) {
        perror("accept error");
        continue;
      }
      /*printf("incoming message..................... !\n \n");*/
      printf("%s:%d connected\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
    }


    for (i = 0; i < num_clients; i++) {

      if (FD_ISSET(clients[i], &read_set)) {
        msg = read(clients[i], buf, sizeof(buf));
        if(msg > 0){
          buf[msg] = 0;
          int savedclnt = clients[i];
          printf("%s \n \n", buf);

          /*for(int p=0;p<num_clients;p++)
          {
            if( clients[p]!= savedclnt){
              write(clients[p],buf,msg);
            }

          }*/
        }

      }

    }
  }
}
```

and my client

```
    int main( )
{   

    struct uci_context *uci;
    uci = uci_init();
    int sockfd;
    int ret;
    struct sockaddr_in dest;
    struct addrinfo hint, *res = NULL;
    struct hostent *host;
    char *hostip;
    char *string;



    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0 )
    {
        puts("Unble to create socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    hostip = ucix_get_option(uci, "pack_mon", "pack_monitoring", "address");
    string = ucix_get_option(uci, "pack_mon", "pack_monitoring", "port");

    bzero(&dest, sizeof(dest));
    dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dest.sin_port = htons(atoi(string));

    memset(&hint, '\0', sizeof hint);
    hint.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;
    hint.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST;

    printf(" %s- %s\n", hostip, string );



    if(isdigit(hostip[0])){
        ret = getaddrinfo(hostip, NULL, &hint, &res);// this is more efficient than inet_addr

        if (ret) {

            exit(1);
        }
    }else if( (host = gethostbyname(hostip)) != 0){

        memcpy((char*)&dest.sin_addr , (char*)host->h_addr , (sizeof dest.sin_addr)+1);

    }else{

        exit(1);
        printf("cannot resolve ip address");
    }  


    if ( connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, sizeof(dest)) < 0 )
    {

        perror("ERROR Connecting" );
        exit(1);
    }else{

        printf("Port number %s is open.....\n",string);
    }


    char *message;
    message = "help";
    write(sockfd,message,strlen(message));


    close(sockfd);
    freeaddrinfo(res);
    return 0;
}
```

FIREWALL RULE

sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 4001 -j ACCEPT

Error is :

192.168.10.155- 4001

ERROR Connecting: Connection refused

and this logs are coming from this codes :

printf(" %s- %s\n", hostip, string );

perror("ERROR Connecting");

exit(1);

Comment: If you want to check `errno` (either directly or indirectly through e.g. `perror`) you need to do it immediately after the failed function. If you use any other function that might set `errno` (which `printf` might indirectly do) then the value of `errno` is undefined.

Comment: First off, are you sure the firewall is open? There could be other rules blocking this before your rule? One way to make sure (maybe you are an expert on iptables but just to make sure..), is to setup something else on that port and test. If that works you are sure the problem is in your code. I only bring it up since you added the firewall rule and it sounds like the problem could be there or in the code. Seting up a netcat "webserver" is one way to test. Run:  netcat -l 5001 < index.html    Then you can try to connect to it and see if you get the page. If it works you know the code is broken

Comment: As for your problem, in the outcommented code if `hostip[0]` is a digit then you don't set `dest.sin_addr`. Assuming that you assume that `hostip` is an IP-address in that case, you don't need to call `getaddrinfo` for that. Just use [`inet_pton`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_pton.3.html). Also, in the other case you should not really be using `strncpy` as the data isn't really a string.

Comment: @FSDaniel  when i run  netcat -l 5001 < index.html and try to connect to it from another remote device, it shows CONNECTION REFUSED but when i connect from same device, it works.

Comment: Regarding the last comment, it indeed seems like you have a firewall issue. That is better solved by going to https://superuser.com/ and asking about that specifically instead.

Comment: @johnleonardonwuzuruigbo, then its either the firewall on the remote machine or on your local machine. I would guess the local machine, but the remote machine could also be blocking outgoing connections to unknown ports, not likely but possible. If you run:    iptables -nL    then you will get all your firewall rules listed in order and you might see the problem there?  You can also check (when you have already started your server program) that it is indeed listening to the correct ip and not just localhost.    netstat -na | grep 5001

Comment: @johnleonardonwuzuruigbo, are you using the same connect command (same ip) on both tries on both machines? Just so it isnt listening on 127.0.0.1 or somehing like that by accident....

Comment: Yes,  i use same ip on both machine. not localhost (127.0.0.1)

Answer (score 0):

Your client has no code to specify the IP address it wants to connect to. All the code that could do that has been commented out.

**Update**: Now your bug is here:

```
    strncpy((char*)&dest.sin_addr , (char*)host->h_addr , sizeof dest.sin_addr);
```

The `strncpy` function is only suitable for C-style strings. You need to use `memcpy` or something similar. This will only copy part of the IP address if any octet other than its last one (in network byte order) is zero.

**Update**: Now your bug is here:

```
    printf("%d\n", connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, sizeof(dest)) < 0);
    perror("hmmmm" );
    exit(1);
```

This calls `connect`, then calls `printf` and then calls `perror`. The problem is, the call to `printf` can modify `errno` even if it succeeds. Thus your call to `perror` can print a totally irrelevant error message.

Comment: this is not the problem, i can connect to other port in my device like 80 or even to google ip and port but cannot connect on this particular port 5001.

Comment: @johnleonardonwuzuruigbo How does it follow from those observations that this is not the problem? In this particular case (forget about the other cases for now), how do you think the OS knows what IP address the client is trying to connect to? And how can you expect it to work if the OS has no idea what IP address you're trying to reach?

Comment: @johnleonardonwuzuruigbo To give an analogy: Say you walked across the street without looking both ways and got hit by a car. Would you say, "It can't be because I didn't look both ways. I didn't look both ways before crossing my living room and didn't get hit by a car. I didn't look both ways before crossing my lawn and didn't get hit by a car."

Comment: @Davide Schwartz, i did as you suggested still not working. I am still getting CONNECTION REFUSED

Comment: @johnleonardonwuzuruigbo Then, *now*, that's not the reason. Assuming you did it correctly, which we can't tell because we can't see the code.

Comment: @johnleonardonwuzuruigbo And, as I expected, you now have a different bug. See my update.

Comment: @DavideSchwartz, updated to  memcpy((char*)&dest.sin_addr , (char*)host->h_addr , sizeof dest.sin_addr);      still NO CONNECTION

Comment: @johnleonardonwuzuruigbo Now you might have a different problem. But, again, it's hard to tell without being able to see the code. Also, it would help to see the precise error. (Which function reported an error and what errror did it report?)

Comment: @DavideSchwartz, i edited my post, below it, you will see the error i get and from which part of the code its logging it from

Comment: @johnleonardonwuzuruigbo See my answer update for your next bug.

Comment: @DavideSchwartz  Edited still print same error message. the problem might be from the server code?